# gitlab - Push to a repository using access_token

Tags: git, oauth, push, token, gitlab

I implemented the oauth2 web flow in order to get access_token from users of my app. With the access_token, I would like to do the following actions:

1. Get user informations
2. Create a repo for this user
3. Push code to this repo (using git push  )

I already successfully get the user information(1) and create a repo(2)

The problem is I can't push code (3), I got "Unauthorized" error.

The command I run:

```
git remote add origin https://gitlab-ci-token<mytoken>@gitlab.com/myuser/myrepo.git  
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You should do

```
git remote add origin https://<access-token-name>:<access-token>@gitlab.com/myuser/myrepo.git
```

Note that this stores the access token as plain text in the `.git\config` file.  To avoid this you can use the git credential system, providing the access token name for "username" and the access token for "password".  This *should* store the credentials in the git credential system in a more secure way.

Comment: this does work, and I found the answer via  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#comment-3965542554

Comment: Hello What is the difference with the above?

Comment: gitlab-ci-token: schema is supposed to use a token generated by Gitlab CI which is hidden, it's even masked in Gitlab CI logs when attempt to print out the env variable it's stored in, but the limtation is it's applicable only to the repo where the Gitlab CI pipeline was started on (perhaps internal, public or group repos, not sure there were changes to permission model since).

oauth2: schema is supposed to use Gitlab user's personal access token and the permissions can be set using Members.

Comment: If gitlab says `git remote add origin git@gitlab.bigcorp.dev:foo/bar/myrepo.git` you should do (watch missed `:` ) :
`git remote add origin "https://oauth2:XXXXXXXXX@gitlab.bigcorp.dev/foo/bar/myrepo.git"`

Comment: And what is <access-token-name>?

Comment: I used this approach but it didn't help me.

Comment: Worked like a charm for my objective.

Comment: error: failed to push some refs to

Comment: @George `access-token-name` is the name of the token that you generated in gitlab. The < and > in the above example should be excluded, the same goes for `access-token` value.

Comment: As of 2024, I can say this still works! I've been trying to achieve a simple push for the past 3 weeks (not an actual DevOps, just trying some stuff) and i've been down every rabbitholes imaginable on the web and ChatGPT didn't help. Glad I got it sorted out. Thanks !

Answer (score 49):

It is also possible to push directly without adding a new remote repository:

```
git push https://gitlab-ci-token:<access_token>@gitlab.com/myuser/myrepo.git <branch_name>
```

This could be particularly useful if you want to pull from and push to different repositories.

Comment: Shouldn't you be hiding your private access token?

Comment: @NickK9 you are right, if I push as described and then type "git config -l" I see that the access token content is visible in git config output

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `git remote set-url`. After creating your access token, do:

```bash
git remote set-url origin https://gitlab-ci-token:${ACCESS_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/<group>/<repo-name>.git
```

Answer (score 2):

I placed the following into my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[credential "https://gitlab.com"]
    username = <insertusername>
    helper = "!f() { echo "username=<insertusername>"; echo "password=$GITLAB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN"; };f"
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked about using `git push`, but some Maven plugins also write to the repository.
Git credentials can be cached in the git credential system or placed in
the `settings.xml` file.

|  | git credential | settings.xml |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `git push` | X |  |
| `maven-release-plugin` |  | X |
| `versions-maven-plugin` | X | X |

Create a (personal, project, group) access token with `write-repository` permission and copy it to a masked (project, group) variable `REPO_TOKEN`.

`project/.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
job:
  script:
    - echo -e 
        "protocol=https\n
         host=gitlab.example.com\n
         username=git\n
         password=$REPO_TOKEN\n"
      | git credential-cache store
    - git commit -m "Upload changes"
    - mvn versions:use-latest-releases
    - mvn release:prepare
    - mvn release:perform
```

`project/pom.xml`:

```
  <scm>
    <url>https://gitlab.example.com/group/${project.artifactId}</url>
    <connection>scm:git:https://gitlab.example.com/group/${project.artifactId}.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://gitlab.example.com/group/${project.artifactId}.git</developerConnection>
  </scm>
  <properties>
    <scm.tag>${env.COMMIT_ID}</scm.tag>
    <project.scm.id>gitlab-scm</project.scm.id>
  </properties>
```

`~/.m2/settings.xml`

```
  <server>
    <id>gitlab-scm</id>
    <username>git</username>
    <password>${env.REPO_TOKEN}</password>
  </server>
```

Answer (score -3):

Push using `gitlab-ci-token` is not currently supported by Gitlab. There is an open [feature request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18106#note_96974129).

Comment: You worded it as if it is not possible at all. For the record, git push is possible but by creating personal token and setting origin URL with it hardcoded. This bears security risks as thoroughly discussed in the feature request link you shared in the answer, for which I'd recommend to hide CI from public on GitLab, even on open source repos. For the record that feature request is about doing it "internally" (non-GitLab CI's could equally push using aforementioned tokens) and with granular rights. That's what it was about.

Comment: @nicolas, if you want more points, you can probably delete your answer.  ;-)