# How do I push to GitLab with a project access token?

Tags: gitlab-ci

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52074198/520162 shows a way to push with an access token. But how do I push with a *project* access token? What is `access-token-name` in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer given by @sytech](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70780627/520162) works but requires you to track token generation count in order to construct a valid username.

With a little experimenting, I found out that you can also use `gitlab-ci-token`:

```sh
git remote set-url origin \
  "https://gitlab-ci-token:${YOURTOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}.git"
```

Answer (score 5):

Project access tokens work exactly the same as personal access tokens. The access token belongs to the [project bot user](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html#project-bot-users) that is created when you create the token.

So, in this case, you should be using the username, which is `project_{project_id}_bot` for the first access token created. For subsequent tokens, the username is `project_{project_id}_bot{bot_count}`

So you would do something like this:

```
git remote add origin \
 "https://project_1234_bot:YOURTOKEN@gitlab.example.com/path/to/project.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

The [gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) is relatively clear about this.
You can use any non-blank value as a username and the project access token as the password.
You can create a remote or push to the URL directly:

```
git push https://bla:glpat-cCGM1-1uUydcshhguzk2@gitlab.com/my-group/my-subgroup/my-project.git
```

What isn't documented on that page, is that the role that you assign to the token actually matters. The token will have the privileges that were assigned to those roles, as described in [this documentation page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html).
That means that your token won't be able to push if you have granted it the role of "Guest" and your repository is private.