# RStudio gitlab: push not working with personal access token

Tags: gitlab, rstudio

I am working in RStudio and I cloned a project lately (using my personal access token, with read_repository and write_repository permissions).
When I want to push my changes to the gitlab repository, I get an error:

> remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
> remote: You must use a personal access token with 'read_repository' or 'write_repository' scope for Git over HTTP.
> remote: You can generate one at https://test.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://test.com/test/test.git/'

Why is the private token not woking anymore? I did not change anything.

Comment: What does `git remote -v` show? Is your token really used? The remote should look like `https://<access-token-name>:<access-token>@test.com`

Comment: Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074414/gitlab-push-to-a-repository-using-access-token ?

Comment: @jschnasse I have the same issue. I don't know where to add the personal access token with gitlab. We have a 2FA hence, need to use access toekn. Was able to setup up with  VS ide and source tree. But, unable to do the same with rstudio. I have posted a Q on https://community.rstudio.com/t/gitlab-enterprise-with-2fa/147316. If you know the steps to setup Access token with Rstudio IDE, can you help me out. Than kyou

Comment: @user5249203 No, not a rstudio user. I would fix it first on command line/terminal and than go back to rstudio.