# git push failing with Access denied to Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, git-push

I am using `git` to push my code to Gitlab.  Following are the commands I am using

```
git clone https://<mygitlab.com>/gke-app-namespace-deploy.git
cd gke-app-namespace-deploy
git checkout -b  master
git branch
   main
   * master
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote set-url origin https://<mygitlab.com>/askar/gke-app-ns-deploy.git
$ git push -u origin master

Username for 'https://<mygitlab.com>': askar
Password for 'https://askar':
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://<mygitlab.com>/askar/gke-app-ns-deploy.git/'
```

The same credentials works while downloading the code but I am getting `Access Denied` message while uploading the code.

What I am trying to do is clone code from `gke-app-namespace-deploy.git' and push to a new repository 'gke-app-ns-deploy.git`. Not sure if `git` by design will allow this.

Comment: maybe you insert wrong password?

Comment: password is correct which I have verified...it is token in this case

Comment: The `HTTP Basic: Access denied` message is coming from some software that `mygitlab.com` is running. It's not from Git itself—Git has no authentication in it at all. So it's something to do with the private GitLab server.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
git remote add origin https://<access-token-name>:<access-token>@gitlab.com/myuser/myrepo.git
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52074198/2675670