# Gitlab access token - git branch --set-upstream-to=origin

Tags: git, gitlab

How is it possible to set `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin` with a Gitlab Access Token?

Adding `git remote add origin` with a Gitlab Access Token works well like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52074198/8839237).

Comment: You shouldn't need to authenticate for each branch. If you already provided authentication for the server configured in your remote (`origin`) then there's nothing you need to do to use that remote with a new branch. Is there a specific problem or error you are experiencing?

Comment: The upstream setting for a branch name is for your local repository, and is effectively just a string (though it has some constraints). Since you set it in your *local* repository (not in a hosted repository) you don't need to authenticate at all, other than to log in to your own laptop in the usual way you do that.

Comment: Typically, the upstream of branch `X` is `origin/X`, for any X. You would do this with `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/X X`, or if you're on branch `X` already, `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/X`. The main constraint here is that `origin/X` must exist *in your local repository*. (It need not exist in any other repository.)

Comment: Note that you *must not* leave off the `X` here. Running `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin` is not what you want to do. (It does have a meaning, but with one exception, you never want this—and that one exception is such that you should almost never want to use it.)