# Gitlab deploy keys for in pipeline push

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

- What I am trying to achieve:

During one step of my Gitlab pipeline, I would like to do a modification on a file and push it as part of the pipeline step.

In order to do so, my admin team gave me a "Deploy Key".

I can see it, it is similar to this (please see screenshot in link)

[deploy key](https://apps.risksciences.ucla.edu/gitlab/help/user/project/deploy_keys/img/deploy_keys_v13_0.png)

However, I am having issues understanding how to use it.

- What I tried:

```
  script:
    - sed -i 's'\n'FOO'\n'BAR'\n'g' src/myfile.java
    - git add src/myfile.java
    - git commit -m "Update file [skip ci]"
    - git push origin HEAD:main
```

This would not work, as I am not passing the deploy key. However, I do not know how to pass it.

I tried this, but still no luck.

```
  script:
    - sed -i 's'\n'FOO'\n'BAR'\n'g' src/myfile.java
    - git add src/myfile.java
    - git config user.name ""
    - git commit -m "Update file [skip ci]"
    - git push origin HEAD:main
```

- Question:

What is the proper way to pass in the "Deploy Key"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gitlab - Push to a repository using access\_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074414/gitlab-push-to-a-repository-using-access-token)